# Is there a way to make this type of table with React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-table

I want to **merge two table that have different columns** into one table, **sort by one same column**.

For example, I have `Dogs` and `Cats` data like below.
Both have `born_date`, `born_place`, `type` columns, but rest of the columns are different.

```
const Dogs = [
  {
    born_date: "2019-02-03",
    born_place: "Earth",
    type: "Dog",
    dog-column-1: "11",
    dog-column-2: "22",
    dog-column-3: "33",
    ...
  }
  , ...
]

const Cats = [
  {
    born_date: "2019-03-01",
    born_place: "Moon",
    type: "Cat",
    cat-column-1: "aa",
    cat-column-2: "bb",
    cat-column-3: "cc",
    cat-column-4: "cc",
    ...
  }
  , ...
]
```

I want to join these two data, **sort by `born_date`**, and insert column headers in between rows where `Dog` and `Cat` shows up next.

I want the table UI to be like this pic below.
[image: sample table UI]

I've searched everywhere, but I just can't find a table like this one.

Is there a way to make this table with React?
Using `react-table` package would be great, since I'm using that package.

Comment: This table structure doesn't really make too much sense. Worst case you would have alternate header and value rows.  Rather, create one table with born date, born place and type and if the user wants to see more details, direct them to a view with the specific details.

Comment: That just screams separate tables to me, where it will be more in the styling of each of the seperate tables can be made to look like one table. Or at the very least have one table with all the columns at least at the top with nullable cells, kind of like how dynamodb will displays its items. `cat-column-1, cat-column-2, dog-column1, dog-column-2`

Comment: I know that it would be easy to just separate tables, but I need to merge them because I need to **sort by same column**. (Not possible with just same styling that look like one table) I could join two tables with null cells, but my real data has hundreds of different columns, so it's not really ideal way to view data.

Comment: Why do you need multiple column headers throughout the table? Why not merge the data in to one data set where each has a source identifier and you do custom css on the cells based on that source? The main part about your request that doesn't make sense is the multiple header situation. Can you explain the use case for needing/wanting this?